# Formula to incorporate Highlighted text & Loop function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to analyze over a 1000 line items,

with different information in all columns ,although certain columns might have duplicate information. 
I can do conditional formatting and highlight the duplicates. What I would now like to do is write a formula, like an "if" function , which somehow is able to select only the the cells highlighted due to conditional formatting.

because certain cells are highlighted and certain aren't I need to know how to differentiate the highlighted from the non highlighted.

Also is there a simple formula to incorporate for duplicates, I know there are ways in VBA where a loop function could be done, so that the program runs and checks that all the data in column A, and checks the duplicates and then runs the function on the corresponding values of those 2 duplicates in some other column and comes out with an answer, but is there a formula for it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two requests.

1. Formula for highlighting duplicates. Assuming your data is in **A1:A1000** put this formula into cell **B1** and drag down:

`=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1000,$A1)`

Duplicate values will return a number greater than 1.

2. To filter the values that are duplicates/highlighted. Apply a filter by selecting your data and hitting Data>Filter (or press Ctrl+Shift+L)

You can then right click on the filter on the new column created above (col **B**) and filter on 1 for unique values/ not 1 for duplicates. Or click on the filter on your original highlighted data and filter by colour to distinguish your duplicates from your unique values